Is a "speculative" move in computer chess, a line which gives rise to evaluation fluctuations?
Am I correct in assuming that a chess engine with a speculative style (for an example Deep Junior or tweaked stockfish), will do a selective search on moves that give rise to a positive/neutral (back and forth) evaluation fluctuation. In human terms translated as moves which are deemed "interesting"
By comparison, a "neutral outlook" engine will plow through all reasonable branches of the search tree equally.
However... this does not answer the question of how you get an engine to consistently pick the move which is speculative after the search (time management) is up.
Why would it naturally favor the speculative line simply for searching that branch deeper? If the evaluation function is independent of styles, and other dryer lines are scored higher, how do you still get it to play the speculative line?
